# Identifier must be declared after EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: sql, database, plsql

With the help of one of StackOverflow's I beat one problem, but now I have another. In my procedure I have this code:

```
 BEGIN 
FOR nr IN 1..102 
LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nr);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
        'BEGIN ' || 
            'IF rec.column_' || nr ||' IS NULL THEN ' || 
                ':x:=1; ' || 
            'ELSE ' ||
                ':x:=0; ' ||
            'END IF; ' ||
        'END; ' 
        USING OUT isnull;
    IF isnull = 1 THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test');
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

END;

Unfortunately when I try to run this procedure I get en error: PLS-00201 identifier 'rec.column_1' must be declared. I' ve found that:

> In the dynamic SQL that you are executing, you refer to OrderStoreData, but no variable of that name is defined in the dynamic SQL.
>   The code executed by the Execute Immediate execute in it's own scope, and everything not defined explicitly as part of the NDS or passed in as a bind variable will be out of scope.

But I do not know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record must be accessed from dynamic sql block, so place it for example in package header. Then it's globally available...

Comment: Ok, but rec is from my cursor. In procedure I use for loop: for rec in cu_um When I put TYPE cu_um IS REF CURSOR, I still get this error.

Comment: You have to define variable in that package so that it is same type as your rec in loop and assign rec to that package variable before loop.